# P.d.f. of weighted linear combination of i.i.d. random variables with uniform distribution

Tags: self-study, uniform-distribution

Given two i.i.d. RVs $x$ and $y$ with uniform distribution in $[0, 1]$, I need to find the p.d.f. of $z = 2x + 3y$.

I have worked through the proof of the general result to get this far to my satisfaction:

$$f_z(z) = \int_{0}^{(z - 3y)/2} \frac{1}{2} f_{xy}((z - 3y)/2, y)dy$$

I have no confidence in taking the next step.

What may be confusing me is: when I worked through the convolution case ($z = x + y$), looking at the plot of $x$ and $y$ (a unit square), I could see that the lower half (where $z <= 1$) was a triangle, but the upper half was a square missing a triangle, motivating setting the lower bound of one of the variables (say $y$) to be $z - 1$ and calculating difference of the missing triangle, yielding a step function as a final solution (for $0 \lt z \le 1$ and $1 \lt z \lt 2$).

In this case the plot is a rectangle. Assuming I need to analyze this in the same way - i.e. there will be a lower triangle and an upper (remainder of a) triangle as $z$ increases.

[image]

I have tried to do this analysis but I am lost at sea. In the convolution case there is a simple value of $z$ ($1$) that defines the boundary between the two cases. I cannot find the boundary in this case. (It feels like something easy that I should know how to do).

I have tried the following. The line dividing the triangles is given by:

$$y = -3/2x + 3$$

But I need this in terms of $z$, so plugging it in:

$$z = 2x + 3(-3/2x + 3) = 2x - 9/2x + 9 = -5/2x + 9$$

But this doesn't make sense since $0 \lt z \lt 5$ and here we have $z=9$ when $x=0$.

Having been a few hours now, I would love a hint.

Comment: **Hint #1:** The upper bound of the integral is incorrect, it cannot involve $y$ since you integrate in $y$.

Comment: **Hint #2:** Work out the constraints on the variable $y$ represented by $0\le y\le 1$ and $0\le \{z-3y\}/2\le 1$.

Comment: **Hint #3:** Figure out the possible values of $z$ and deduce the range of $z$.

Comment: Thanks, Xi'an :) For Hint #1: thank you, that was indeed a silly error. For Hint #2: if I work through this inequality, I get $(z-2)/3 \le y \le z/3$, however since $0 \le y \le 1$ the lower bound should just be $0$ and the upper bound $1$, since, $0 \le z \le 5$ and $5/3 \gt 1$, unless I am still mistaken?! For Hint #3: Am I wrong about $0 \le z \le 5$?

Comment: for Hint #2, $y$ has to satisfy _both_ $0 \le y \le 1$ _and_ $(z-2)/3 \le y \le z/3$ and you cannot throw the second away. For instance, if $z=3>2$, which is a possibility, $y$ must be larger than $0$ and larger than $(3-2)/3$, which means it must be larger than $1/3$.

Comment: Because $2X$ and $3Y$ are non-identical uniformly distributed variables, this is a special case of the duplicate.  The specific error presented in the current question concerns drawing the wrong rectangle, which has little to do with solving the problem.